# alljoyn framework ios error: cannot parse the debug map for

Tags: ios, objective-c, p2p, alljoyn

Hi I am trying to run Alljoyn ios chat sample with Xcode 7 and IOS-9
but facing following errors :

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: cannot parse the debug map for 
"/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AllChatz.app/AllChatz":
No such file or directory
```

I have disable bitcode settings from project and target but not finding any way to solve this issue.
is there any any solution? or any alternative to this how can i run this demo successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add openSSL `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` static library.

You can get it from source with this build script: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Comment: I downloaded the sample project from git but these two libraries you specified are not available in the source code.

Comment: You need to build library with ./build-libssl.sh

Comment: I have build lib successfully and added the libs in my project but still getting same errors

Answer (score 2):

Switch ENABLE_BITCODE to NO in build settings helped me